# Updating a group by with incrementing values

Tags: sql-server, increment

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 that looks like this:

```
ID  DataDate    DataHour Value  UpdateDate  UpdateTime
23  09/03/2019   11       65.2  09/15/2019   04:15:209
16  09/03/2019   11       66.7  09/15/2019   04:15:209
26  09/03/2019   11       62.3  09/15/2019   04:15:209
27  09/03/2019   11       69.8  09/15/2019   04:15:209
15  09/03/2019   11       59.2  09/15/2019   04:15:209
22  09/02/2019   11       45.2  09/15/2019   04:15:209
41  09/02/2019   11       36.7  09/15/2019   04:15:209
25  09/02/2019   11       62.3  09/15/2019   04:15:209
21  09/02/2019   11       79.8  09/15/2019   04:15:209
12  09/02/2019   11       19.2  09/15/2019   04:15:209
17  09/02/2019   11       19.2  09/15/2019   04:15:209
```

I'd like to update the UpdateDate and UpdateTime columns, as follows:
- Group by DataDate, DataHour
- Order by ID Desc (e.g. highest first)
- Leave the first row of the group as-is
- For each remaining row in the group, subtract one hour from UpdateTime
- If the updated UpdateTime goes to the previous day (i.e. hour = 23), decrement the UpdateDate by 1 day

Result should look like:

```
ID  DataDate    DataHour Value  UpdateDate  UpdateTime
23  09/03/2019   11       65.2  09/15/2019   02:15:209
16  09/03/2019   11       66.7  09/15/2019   01:15:209
26  09/03/2019   11       62.3  09/15/2019   03:15:209
27  09/03/2019   11       69.8  09/15/2019   04:15:209
15  09/03/2019   11       59.2  09/15/2019   00:15:209
22  09/02/2019   11       45.2  09/15/2019   02:15:209
41  09/02/2019   11       36.7  09/15/2019   04:15:209
25  09/02/2019   11       62.3  09/15/2019   03:15:209
21  09/02/2019   11       79.8  09/15/2019   01:15:209
12  09/02/2019   11       19.2  09/14/2019   23:15:209
17  09/02/2019   11       19.2  09/15/2019   00:15:209
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.UpdateTime = DATEADD(hour,-1,g.UpdateTime), t.UpdateDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,DATEADD(hour,-1,g.UpdateTime)) = 23 THEN DATEADD(day,-1,g.UpdateDate) ELSE g.UpdateDate END
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) As ID, DataDate, DataHour, MAX(UpdateDate) As UpdateDate, MAX(UpdateTime) As UpdateTime
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY DataDate, DataHour, ID
    ORDER BY DataDate, DataHour, ID DESC
) g
ON g.id = t.id
```

But this is not incrementing through the group properly.  Not sure if I need a window function to help with this.

Comment: Maybe EXCEPT instead of INNER JOIN? Test with a select first, of course.

Comment: How do you define the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your date and time values separated makes this difficult (as did the fact that the time was misformatted), but this should do what you want.

First, create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID int, DataDate date, DataHour int, Value decimal(9,1), UpdateDate date, UpdateTime Time(3))
INSERT INTO #tmp Values
    (23,'09/03/2019', 11, 65.2,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (16  ,'09/03/2019',   11       ,66.7  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (26  ,'09/03/2019',   11       ,62.3  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (27  ,'09/03/2019',   11       ,69.8  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (15  ,'09/03/2019',   11       ,59.2  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (22  ,'09/02/2019',   11       ,45.2  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (41  ,'09/02/2019',   11       ,36.7  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (25  ,'09/02/2019',   11       ,62.3  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (21  ,'09/02/2019',   11       ,79.8  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (12  ,'09/02/2019',   11       ,19.2  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9'),
    (17  ,'09/02/2019',   11       ,19.2  ,'09/15/2019', '04:15:20.9')
```

Then here is the code that will generate the desired output. Modify this and put it into UPDATE statements as needed:

```
;WITH Base as (
    SELECT 
        DataDate, 
        DataHour,
        Max(UpdateDate) as BaseDate,
        Max(UpdateTime) as BaseTime
    FROM #tmp t2
    GROUP BY DataDate, 
        DataHour
),
AdjData as (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        t.DataDate,
        t.DataHour,
        t.Value,
        Cast(BaseDate as Datetime) + Cast(BaseTime as DateTime) as BaseDateTime
        ,row_number() over (Partition by t.DataDate, t.DataHour ORDER BY t.Id Desc) as Adj
    FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN Base b
        ON t.DataDate = b.DataDate
        AND t.DataHour = b.DataHour
    )
SELECT Id,
    DataDate,
    DataHour,
    Value,
    Cast(Dateadd(hour, -(Adj-1), BaseDateTime) AS date) as UpdateDate,
    Cast(Dateadd(hour, -(Adj-1), BaseDateTime) AS Time(3)) as UpdateTime
FROM AdjData
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  I added the UPDATE just above the last select and joined the full select on id, and that did it.